# C# ABP framework: Can AbpInterceptor be used in regular dotnet service class (non-application service) to intercept method calls?

Tags: c#, interceptor, abp

Can AbpInterceptor be used in regular dotnet service class (non-application service) to intercept method calls?

I am developing a non-ABP microservice to fetch data from third-party Uri. I would like to log the request and response details whenever any method is called inside that microservice.

I have tried HttpMessageHandler, Castle.DynamicProxy. But still can not log the requests and responses details.

I have also tried AbpInterceptor, but the official document is insufficient to answer my query:
https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Aspect-Oriented-Programming

```
public class NonAppServiceInterceptor : AbpInterceptor, ITransientDependency
{
    private readonly ILogger<NonAppServiceInterceptor > _logger;

    public NonAppServiceInterceptor (ILogger<NonAppServiceInterceptor > logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async override Task InterceptAsync(IAbpMethodInvocation invocation)
    {
        LogInvocation(invocation);
        await invocation.ProceedAsync();
    }

    private void LogInvocation(IAbpMethodInvocation invocation)
    {
        /* Access to all the information about the method execution
         * including method, class and provided arguments */

        _logger.LogInformation(
            "Executing the method: " +
            invocation.Method.Name +
            " of class " +
            invocation.TargetObject.GetType().FullName
        );
    }
}
```

Have anyone done similar things before? I need some direction for this. Thanks for your help!